# PrestaShop Paypal addon error 500

Tags: paypal, prestashop

I have a PrestaShop installation with the following versions:

- PrestaShop 1.6.0.14
- PayPal add-on v3.11.1

When I try to checkout through Paypal, the server throws a 500 error. By checking the log file I've found this error:

`Property Customer->passwd is empty at line 872 in file classes/ObjectModel.php`

I suspect that the problem it's not actually the Paypal add-on, but as it's the only payment method currently supported by the site, I'm unable to check my suspicion.

Any idea?

Edit: It seems to happen only with logged in customers.

Comment: Could you check if the customers have a guest account? Or does it happen with all customers?

Comment: have you tested it with any other customer account or with any other payment method like bankwire etc?

Comment: The error seems to happen only when the user is logged in the system, as it doesn't happen the first time that the customer tries to pay. After several test I've found that the error is related with another add on that enables one-page checkout.